# React Native: Unable to emulate on Genymotion

Tags: react-native, genymotion

I did following command to emulate my react native app on genymotion, but I got an error.

```
expo start -a
```

Here is the error.

> This computer is not authorized to debug the device. Please follow the
>   instructions here to enable USB debugging:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options.
>   If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom
>   Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

Comment: Did you do what the error stated?

Comment: I posted error in the question

Comment: "This computer is not authorized to debug the device"

Comment: "If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory." ... you read that part as well?

Comment: Just read a answer from @xyingsoft and doing it

Comment: Yes, set android sdk directory in genymotion, but no luck. after I set android sdk tools in system path, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it might not have been able to find your adb path. You have to install adb and set adb path in genymotion and system.

Open genymotion and go to Settings > ADB tab, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it to your Android SDK directory. And then please make sure that android sdk tools is in your system path.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;path\to\android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Real example on windows, android sdk tools directory path depends on installation directory:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

#### or

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools
```

Comment: Do i have to install android studio?